# Cannot create database in denied permission in 'master'

Tags: sql-server

I did checked the `Security->Logins` there are 2 in the list:
`BUILTIN\Users` and `sa`

I've tried adding `dbcreator` role for `BUILTIN\Users` but it failed having this error: `Cannot alter the server role 'dbcreator', because it does not exist or you do not have permission`

```
SQL Server 2016
Windows Authentication
```

Comment: What login did you use?

Comment: Windows Authentication. Default one. Desktop name and no password

Comment: Your login must not have sa rights.  Try logging in using the sa account.

Comment: I have tried using the sa account but then it says Cannot connect to Desktop-r52n528\SQLEXPRESS. Login Failed to user 'sa'

Comment: execute `select IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin')` to see if you are sysadmin

Comment: ...But I think if you see only two logins you do not have any server-level permissions: you see only YOUR login, i.e. you've logged in being the member of  `BUILTIN\Users`, and `sa` login is visible to everyone